# How to 'await' a WebClient.UploadStringAsync request?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-7, webclient

The async pattern seems to be call an asynchronous, then yield control after `await`ing a result, which makes a lot of sense.

However the `WebClient` class `UploadStringAsync` method does not return a `Task`, instead it return void and so cannot be `await`ed. Instead an event handler can be defined. e.g.

```
public async Task FlushQueue() {
    attempt = 0;
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    while ((queue.Count > 0) && (attempt < ALLOWED_ATTEMPTS)) {

        // Copy 10 items from queue and put into buffer ...
        ...
        wc.UploadStringCompleted += (s, e) => {
            // if response 200 
            // Remove 10 sent items from queue
            // else attempt++ 
        };
        wc.UploadStringAsync("http://example.com/blah", "POST", buffer);

        // In an ideal world we could call UploadStringAsync like,
        // var response = await wc.UploadStringAsync("http://example.com/blah", "POST", buffer);
    }
}
```

However, this does not await a response and instead quickly rattles through lauching the maximum number of web requests.

Is there a way to yield flow back outside of `FlushQueue` until the event handler callback is executed?

Edit: This is for a Windows Phone 7.5 project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [`UploadStringTaskAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159564.aspx), which returns a `Task<string>`.

The async suffixes on pre-4.5 `WebClient` methods are unfortunate as they don't match the TAP signatures you'd expect. In general, in that situation it's recommended that API designers use `TaskAsync` instead of a `Async` as a suffix - which is exactly what `WebClient` did... hence `DownloadStringTaskAsync` etc.

You might also want to consider using [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) instead of `WebClient`.

Comment: Thanks, that's great, looked at the docs for `UploadStringTaskAsyc` and it returns the 'server response' as a string, but doesn't say what is the format of the string - I need the HTTP repsonse code e.g. 200, do I need to parse that string?

Comment: Also is HttpClient now the preferred way of doing this kind of thing? This is the first I have heard of it... Searching for 'POST data from Windows Phone' has resulted in WebClient, HttpWebRequest and others but not HttpClient e.g. [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637320(v=vs.95).aspx#unsupported) and [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.90).aspx). Is there a good resource for finding out the best current accepted practices?

Comment: As far as I know, `HttpClient` on Windows Phone is available as a NuGet package but is still in beta version. So I wouldn't call it "preferred way", but "preferred way to be" ;) For more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: @Brendan: I hadn't noticed that this was Windows Phone. Are you using WP7, or WP7.5? I don't know the format of the string returned, but I'd expect it to be the actual content. I'm not sure how you'd get the full response.

Comment: @Jon it's Windows Phone 7.5, I did what KooKiz suggested and downloaded the Microsoft libraies for `HttpClient` and it seems to work fine. Thank guys!

Comment: @Brendan: Cool - glad it works. In your next question, please be specific about the platform, as it can make a big difference.

Comment: OK, although I've seen edits where people took the references out of the title and put it in the tags instead, guess I misunderstood the posting etiquette

Comment: @Brendan: I would personally put it in the tags *and* the body of the question (but not the title).